# Python : I want to know the frequency of a wav file per millisecond

Tags: python-3.x

I understood my earlier question but this just happened

How do I find the frequency of a wav file per millisecond ???

Comment: Frequency per millisecond... *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

```
import wave
f = wave.open( 'test.wav' )
f.getframerate()
```

Look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/wave.html).